# He finally got his car repaired that had been driven by his girlfriend that John told you about

Tags: relative-clauses, run-on-sentences

Is it clear who or what John was talking about:

> He finally got his car repaired that had been driven by his girlfriend that John told you about.

Comment: Is this a sentence you've written or are you trying to decypher someone else's meaning?

Comment: The meaning of a sentence can be clear, but that is no garanty as to its being grammatical or idiomatic.

Comment: The meaning of a sentence can be unclear without being ungrammatical or unidiomatic. Not rewriting would be cruel and unusual punishment to the reader.

Comment: The words "car" and "girlfriend" should be specified by "the", rather than by 'his".

Comment: You should rewrite it. The grammar is awful, and the meaning is not clear. Perhaps something like: "The car that had been driven by the girlfriend that John told you about, has finally been repaired."

Comment: @BillyKerr Grammatically incorrect, I'm afraid. The comma should not be there.

Comment: @PrimeMover - Your opinion perhaps. However, after a long complex subject it's perfectly fine to add a comma before the verb. This is a stylistic choice, but it's optional here. It has nothing to do with the grammar really.

Comment: There's "clear" in the sense of "unambiguous" and "clear" in the sense of "readable". The sentence might be the former, but it certainly isn't the latter.

Comment: Perhaps: "He finally got his car repaired (the one that had been driven by his girlfriend, whom John told you about)." It's still unstructured stream-of-consciousness, but at least it's grammatical and unambiguous.

Answer (score 9):

The sentence has very bad style and arguable grammar, but if you said it just like this in normal conversation without context, the meaning would be clear: John told you about some other guy's girlfriend, the girlfriend drove that other guy's car, and that other guy got the car repaired.

That said, if you want to be be pedantic, it's possible to parse it in ways that give other meanings. For instance, it's possible that John is the "other guy". It's also possible that John told you about the car, rather than about the girlfriend. In both these cases, the style is even worse than with the normally understood meaning above.

Comment: What would be the probability of the original sentence being interpreted as "John told you about the car rather than about the girlfriend"? 5%? What is there in the original sentence that rings with "bad style and arguable grammar"?

Comment: @tes389 What is the value of debating the exact probability that someone would interpret this sentence in the other way?  I agree with gotube that most native speakers will infer this same meaning but 1) percentage chance to misinterpret is not an analysis of English sentences I've ever seen before and 2) there is already universal agreement in these various comments and answers that this sentence is unnecessarily awkward and should be rewritten. What is your goal here?

Comment: "the meaning would be clear" - I don't think so. Depending how it is spoken aloud, the sentence might easily be instead transcribed with commas like this: "He finally got his car repaired, that had been driven by his girlfriend, that John told you about." Here the speaker is reminding the listener about the car in two different ways: it is the car driven by his girlfriend, and it is the car that John told you about. The interpretation of what John is referring to is unclear unless we assume the punctuation transcribed is definitely and intentionally accurate (unlikely given the bad grammar).

Comment: @GrandOpener "What is the value of debating the exact probability that someone would interpret this sentence in the other way?" The question asked was: "Is it clear who or what John was talking about"

Comment: We can get away with using clumsy sentences like that in conversations because conversations offer the opportunity to ask clarifying questions if the meaning's not immediately clear.

Comment: @usul What about having just one comma in the sentence,  "He finally got his car repaired that had been driven by his girlfriend, that John told you about." ? What exactly is there in the original sentence that makes you think it has bad grammar?

Comment: @BenM We can get away with using clumsy sentences like that in conversations because the use of pauses, stress and intonation clarifies the ambiguity, doesn't it?

Comment: @tes389 I'm not an expert but in my experience, a "that" relative clause (here, "that had been driven") should directly follow the noun phrase that it modifies, which this doesn't (it follows an entire clause). A grammatical version would be "He finally got his car that had been driven by his girlfriend, that John told you about, repaired."

Comment: The default is that a prepositional phrase refers to the closest preceding phrase for which it makes sense. That's why we normally assume that John told you about the girlfriend, not the car.

Comment: "... if you said it just like this in normal conversation without context, the meaning would be clear ...". No. No it wouldn't. Spoken conversational English uses lots of constructions that aren't correct written English, but they don't look at all like this.

Answer (score 4):

> He finally got his car repaired that had been driven by his girlfriend
> that John told you about.

- John told the listener about the girlfriend of the person to whom "he" refers.
- "He" finally got his car repaired.
- The car was previously driven by "his" girlfriend.

The sentence is incorrectly constructed however - the prepositions do not connect properly and there are too many of them to clearly convey the intended meaning - they provide confusing and unnecessary information.

Instead, the speaker might say:

"**He finally got the car that his girlfriend used to drive repaired.**"

...leaving out the information that is not important.

If the listener needed to determine which girlfriend was being spoken of, he could ask:

**"Which girlfriend is that?"**

and the response would be:  "**The one that John told you about.**"

Comment: Did John speak about the girlfriend or about the car? Are you sure?

Comment: I would say there are two titles: First the car, second "girlfriend"

Comment: @tes389  It's impossible to disprove an author's intent if you assume it doesn't correspond meaningfully to their speech - but ordinarily you couldn't have two "that" clauses determining the same noun phrase, so the second must refer to the "girlfriend".

Comment: @BadZen "ordinarily"? You mean, there are exceptions?

Comment: I meant "ordinarily" in contrast with " if we assume the author's intent doesn't correspond meaningfully to their speech".    There is also some use of multiple determiners offset by commas, in the context of fictional writing, to produce a certain kind of narrative emphasis:  "He could not believe Jean would do this.  Jean, *who had been by his side from the start*, *who had always been agreeable and loyal*..."

Comment: @BadZen What about "He finally got his car repaired that had been driven by his girlfriend, that John told you about."?

Comment: If you want to make it clear you are talking about the girlfriend, you could use "who John told you about" instead of "that John told you about", but it's still too much information in one sentence - and too many clauses.   Notice the order of "repaired" and "that had been driven..." as well.   It's better to locate the determiner right after the noun, as in my example above.

Comment: @BadZen Have you noticed the comma after "girlfriend"?

Answer (score 3):

The OP's sentence is relatively short but it is clumsy, confusing, and on paper, quite ambiguous.

> 1. He finally got his car repaired = OK

> 2. **that** had been driven **by** his girlfriend

The subordinate clause is grammatical but possibly ambiguous. Does he have other cars that need to be repaired? If we can replace the passive with the active voice it will be easier to parse:

> (i) …, **the one** his girlfriend had been driving, =
> the owner possesses a few other cars but his girlfriend drives only *one* of them.
> (ii)… **which** his girlfriend had been driving, = without context, the possibility of their being more than one car has not been eliminated, but the implication is stronger.

- *He finally got the car **that his girlfriend had been driving,** repaired.* =   Which car was repaired? The one his girlfriend was using.
- He finally got his car repaired, **the one his girlfriend had been driving.** = OK
- He finally got his car, **which his girlfriend had been driving**, repaired. = The girlfriend also drove the car. If the parenthetical clause (in bold) were removed, the sentence would still make sense.

> 3.**that John told you about**. = This is the most ambiguous part.

Did John talk about the car that needed repairing or his girlfriend? It could be either.  Clarity is not always about being concise, sometimes you need more words in order to express a fairly complex idea.

> **The car that John told you about**, the one his girlfriend was driving, it's finally been repaired.

> That girlfriend, **who**(m) **John told you about,** had been driving his car. It's finally been repaired.

The old fashioned object pronoun “whom" can be safely left out. Barely anyone says it nowadays and if they do, oftentimes they should have used the subject pronoun "who" instead!

Comment: What is the balance of probabilities of interpretation of John talking about the car vs. John talking about his girlfriend? Obviously, not 50/50?

Comment: @tes389  What kind of trick question is that? Can any native speaker or linguist give a percentage? How would they support it? They would have to personally interview hundreds of people.

Comment: I was obviously asking for your rough subjective estimate. Are these probabilities of the same order?

Comment: I can say this with confidence, the sentence is inherently ambiguous and open to several interpretations.

Comment: And yet this ambiguity is clarified in oral speech by inserting pauses, by stress and by change in intonation, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, usually and presumably the people speaking know each other.  Do you know who "John" is? Is the girlfriend John's or a third person? That's why I said *on paper*. It's ambiguous, and it won't stop being ambiguous because we lack the necessary information.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, a relative clause refers to the last word before it that it could refer to, and which makes sense in context. (If you want to look up more, search for *antecedent* or *referent*.)  If you break this rule, you should make sure it’s clear from context what each clause refers to.  (For example, a *who* clause could only refer to a person, so it would clearly mean the girlfriend and not the car.)  You should consider breaking a sentence with multiple clauses into two or three simpler sentences.  In written English, this sentence would be rewritten to be less ambiguous.

So: “He finally got his car repaired,” is a simple main clause.

“That had been driven by his girlfriend,” is an adjectival clause, and the immediately preceding referent is “car.” The only other possible referent is “he.”  If we meant that, though, we’d say, “The man who had been driven by his girlfriend to get his car repaired ....” or more naturally, “His girlfriend drove him to get his car repaired.”  So it’s the car that she drove.

Similarly, John could have told you about any of the people or objects in the sentence, but the referent immediately before the clause is “girlfriend.”  So, John told you about the girlfriend, who drove the car.  This could be made clearer by using *who* instead of *that* for a person.  If both clauses referred to the car instead, we might say something like:

> He got the car John told you about, the one that was driven by his girlfriend, repaired.

> He got the car repaired that his girlfriend drove and John told you about.

> He got the car that John told you about repaired. His girlfriend drove it.

This sentence also seems to use *that* informally for both restrictive and non-restrictive clauses.  The man presumably does not have other girlfriends that John did not tell you about, so it’s not telling you *which one* of his girlfriends it means.  In more formal English, a non-restrictive clause like this should be set off with a comma and use either *which* or *who*. (In very formal written English, it might even end with, “..., whom John told you about,” or some people even think it should be, “..., about whom John told you.”)

Comment: I have seen a lot of sentences where a relative clause does not refer to the last word before it. What about 
'He finally got his car repaired that had been driven by his girlfriend who hardly passed her driving test just a year before that John told you about.'
Or rather,
'He finally got his car repaired - that had been driven by his girlfriend who hardly passed her driving test just a year before - that John told you about.'

Comment: @tes389 I would say both those sentences are incorrect. Note that they do have antecedent reference (the car “had been driven” and the girlfriend “hardly passed”) except for the final clause, which is a dangling modifier. I can’t tell what it’s supposed to refer to at all, and *that* is a confusing way to introduce it here.

Comment: @tes389 It is very common to change the order of the sentence if it remains clear what each clause refers to from context. This is especially likely to happen in extemporaneous speech, where thoughts wander. For example, since *who* could only refer to the girlfriend and not the car, a *who* clause could appear out of order.